# I made a mistake and moved a surface texture

Tags: rendering, mesh, armature

Now some of the triangles are messed up and the back of one arm shows through a transparent inside to the front of the arm's texture in reverse.

From the popular voxel based game ROBLOX, [here is my .blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/p7a1xrztsjct4bp/RigDone.blend/file). Either tell me how to fix it, or fix it for me, thanks in advance.

[image: The error]
<sub>(source: [ezimba.com](http://www.ezimba.com/work/150812C/ezimba15546437914800.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have just moved down a tris of vertices. Select them and grab it on the Z axis with snap to vertex active as in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

Moving faces in the 3D view don't interfere with their UV data, so the texture should come back to his initial state (not streched) without further operations.

Comment: Thanks alot! I have another question though, do you know how I could add extra joints to make elbows and knees without altering the textures?

Comment: Maybe is better that you post this as another question, there is not much space here in the comments and you'll not get enough visibility. Don't forget to pack texture in the file before uploading it.